# Retrieve only unread/unseen notifications

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

Is there a way to retrieve only unread/unseen notifications from the Notification feed?

If not what is the best way to get the "nextId" which has the unread/unseen notification without iterating through the all the notifications from the beginning.

Alternatively, is there a way to remove the link to an activity in the notification feed without affecting the original activity?

Comment: what does this mean " is there a way to remove the link to an activity in the notification feed without affecting the original activity?"

Comment: For example, Lets say I have feed-2, feed-3 ... feed-n all following feed-1. if I add a new activity to a feed-1 and lets say the activity id is 1, all other feeds also gets the activity id 1. 

Now if I delete the activity id 1, then it disappears from all the feeds. Can i selectively disassociate the activity id 1 from a certain feed, let's say feed-3?

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli - so is there any way to retrieve only unread notifications?